# Bounds issue on geoserver's side

Tags: geoserver

I have 2 layers under EPSG:3857 and one map under EPSG:4326 to represent the world. 
When I preview my aggregation of layers, here's what is shown : 
[image]
In fact, this is what it should be displayed, on North America coast and Europe:
[image]

Check the scale which is insane, I had to zoom in a lot.

Why did my layers don't fit the world? My two layers are SQL View Layers and the config is the same : 
[image]

Comment: you must set the EPSG:4326 one (the USA one) as EPSG:4326 - GeoServer can then reporject it for you

Comment: @iant I don't understand... I think you wanted to say from 3857 to 4326 but I don't know which layer. I have a line layer, a point layer, a world layer and I aggregate all of them. Should I set native SRS as 3857 then data SRS as 4326, native bound based on SRS and reproject native SRS ? There is a lot of fields and I don't understand, French translation is actually a little messy

Comment: set the declared srs to match the file projection - for all the "small" layers set it as 4326

Comment: Well... That worked ..  do you want to write the answer or should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers that are "too small" are in lat/lon (EPSG:4326) while your countries layer (and map) is in Web Mercator (EPSG:3857).

If you tell GeoServer that the 4326 layers are in 3857 then it will draw the layers without reprojecting them and they will appear to be down on [Null Island](http://www.nullisland.com/). To fix this you need to let GeoServer know that they are in 4326 (ideally the .prj file would do this) so that it knows they need converting.